# Error when upgrading service databases

Tags: 2013, powershell, upgrade

So, I have recently run a load of CU's (July 2017) and now my Search crawl isn't working.

Reviewing the error logs, it seems to be because my databases are now too far out lf date. Chexcking the database upgrade level confirms this:

> SP-SQLAlias-Service SP_PROD_Search SearchAdminDatabase Database is in
>   compatibility range and upgrade is recommended
>   SP-SQLAlias-Service
>   SP_PROD_Search_AnalyticsReportingStore
>   SearchAnalyticsReportingDatabase Database is too old and upgrade is
>   required SP-SQLAlias-Service SP_PROD_Search_CrawlStore
>   SearchGathererDatabase Database is too old and upgrade is required
>   SP-SQLAlias-Service SP_PROD_Search_LinksStore SearchLinksDatabase
>   Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended

I have tried running an upgrade on this:

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase | where {$_.Name -eq "SP_PROD_Search_CrawlStore"}$db.Upgrade()
```

...but this returns an error:

```
Exception calling "Upgrade" with "0" argument(s): "The global session cannot be used to perform an upgrade operation."At line:1 char:1+ (Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.Name -eq "SP_PROD_Search_CrawlStore"}).Upgrade()+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

(I'd really like to avoid re-creating the Search Service...!)

Thank you, all.

Comment: You need to run the Config Wizard on all of your SharePoint servers.

Comment: I have - several times. Should I just keep on running the wizard until it gives a good result?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you can't upgrade using 'psconfig', you'll need to recreate the service search application. Keep in mind (!) before you upgrade the platform, you must suspend the search application service:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/72addaae-efe5-40bb-8c86-294e10266878(v=office.16).aspx#updatesearchcomp